# Load Map at User Location - Google Maps in iOS

Tags: google-maps, swift3, xcode8

Having a lot of trouble getting a google map to load with the user's location.

I've been using a number of resources, especially this one, but it was last updated over a year ago and doens't work well in Swift 3 / Xcode 8
(https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial

Anyone have some sample code or tweaks to share that could help me accomplish this?

Main issues with the RayWenderlich tutorial - won't let me run the functions in the extension. The imported classes in the extension are redundant and thrown an error. Without those classes, you can't use an extension. So, I've tried using just a function but then I get an error trying to call 
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)

Comment: Trying to get the user location, and then use that to set the map location upon start. So, the map should load with the user location in the center.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Variable

```
var centerMap = true
```

ViewDidLoad

```
super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        print("locationserviceson")
        centerMap = true
```

Function that Updates when User Location Changes

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations location: [CLLocation]) {
    print("yes")

    userLocation = location.last!
    if centerMap == true {
        self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: userLocation.coordinate, zoom: 15.0)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        centerMap == false
    }

}
```